# How to replace OWL Carousel image with embed code on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I am using [OWL Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) to display projects and now I want to replace this embed code to clicked image:

```
<embed src="http://sample.biz/scratch.swf" wmode="direct" quality="high" flashvars="project_filePath=http://sample.biz/public/upload/scratchproject/2016/02/Ignition.sb2" width="480px" height="400px" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

I want show embed code when user click to any of the images.

Any Idea how to do this with `OWL Carousel`.

**[My JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L0p5as86/2/)**.

### **HTML Part:**

```
<div id="example" class="carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/vga" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/vga" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/vga" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/vga" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

### jQuery Part:

```
var currentIndex = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#example").owlCarousel({
    items: 5,
    singleItem: true,
    afterMove: function() {
      currentIndex = this.currentItem;
    }
  }).on('changed.owl.carousel', function(property) {
    currentIndex = property.item.index;
    console.log(currentIndex);
  });

});

$(document.body).on('click', '#example .item img', function() {
  var embedData = '<embed src="http://sample.biz/scratch.swf" wmode="direct" quality="high" flashvars="project_filePath=http://sample.biz/public/upload/scratchproject/2016/02/Ignition.sb2" width="480px" height="400px" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L0p5as86/7/)**

You could use the `replaceWith` :

```
$(this).replaceWith(embedData);
```

Hope this helps.